# Make sum of num_importe by the entidad code sql

Tags: sql

My code:

```
select distinct entidad, sum(cast(num_importe as float))
from envio_remesa
inner join remesa 
on envio_remesa.id = remesa.envio_remesa_id 
where remesa.envio_remesa_id = 3 and remesa.tipo_doc='201';
```

The case is that for example I have two different "***entidades***"(suppose 18 and 21, but it can be any number), and I want to group in two different records the **sum** of the **"num_importe"** for the "entidad" 18, and the **sum** of the **"num_importe"** for the "entidad" 21.How could I do it?

What I want to come out:

```
entidad   num_importe    
18        92.300,00    
21        56.000,20    
432       120.000,32    
12        12.232,12
```

Comment: at the end add `group by entidad` should be OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoud use `group by` (by the way, distinct is useless here)

```sql
select entidad, sum(cast(num_importe as float))
from envio_remesa
inner join remesa 
on envio_remesa.id = remesa.envio_remesa_id 
where remesa.envio_remesa_id = 3 and remesa.tipo_doc='201'
group by entidad;
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, but why distinct is useless here?

Comment: when you use group by on some columns; you can be sure that you will not have several same rows : you can have 2 rows very similar but there will be at least one column value(you can use group by on several column) different.

Comment: And if i want add another column to the query but not grouping by(only group by 'entidad'), how should i do it?

Comment: Please give more details. It is hard to give a general answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select entidad, sum(cast(num_importe as float))
from envio_remesa er inner join
     remesa r
     on er.id = r.envio_remesa_id 
where r.envio_remesa_id = 3 and r.tipo_doc = '201'
group by entidad;
```

Note:  You should qualify `entidad` and `num_importe` so it is clear what table they come from.

Also, I added table aliases into the query.  They make the query easier to write and to read.